# How can I not register the mxGraph changes so the undo event should not contain the changes?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

Basically, when you remove/add/edit any cells in the mxGraph it automatically saves the changes and when you undo it put it back the changes.

Now, I have a scenario where I am going to delete a cell/element and when the user clicks on undo the deleted element should not appear again.

The below code gets the changes from the event:

```
 var undoRedoHandler = function(undoManager, event) {
     var changes = event.properties.edit.changes;
}
```

Here event will be storing the changes 
and I want to skip the few changes by not storing in the event.